# How to change password used to logon to Chrome RDP for Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, passwords

I am having trouble logging in to my virtual machine. When I click the RDP button on the virtual machine page it opens a window requesting a username and password (photo attached). I set this up a long time ago so I can not remember the password, I have tried a couple of common passwords I use as well as the password to my google account but none have worked. How can I recover or change this username and password. I don’t know if this is the right place to ask but I have tried contacting google cloud support and it seems I can not get this kind of help without paying.
[The login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKt2Y.jpg)?

Edit: For anyone else looking for the answer you need to go the the VM page in google cloud console, click the 3 dots next to the RDP button and select create windows password. This will give you a temp password which you can change after logging in

Answer (score 0):

If you have permissions `compute.instances.admin` and `iam.serviceAccountUser` by following the [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-passwords-for-windows-instances#generating_a_password) you can generate new passwords for your windows VM.